# Eclipse C++ - how to suppress a warning for a specific line?

Tags: c++, eclipse

In the C++ version of Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0) I'm getting an unused variable warning.  I'd like to suppress this warning for a certain line, not  for any other cases of unused variables in the current project or any other project.  Here is a screenshot of a test program:

[image]

As you can see, the `// @suppress("unused")` does not help as I was hoping it would.  Here are the various combinations of suppression comment syntax I've tried:

```
int unusedVar1; // @suppress("unused")

int unusedVar2; // @Suppress("unused")

int unusedVar3; // @Suppress("Unused")

int unusedVar4; // @SuppressWarning("Unused")

int unusedVar5; // @SuppressWarning("unused")
```

Clicking on the yellow warning triangle links to the Project Properties and Window Preferences menus, but all the settings there would change things for all lines in a program, which I don't want to do.

Is there a way to suppress a certain warning for a certain line in C++ Eclipse?

Comment: `(void)unusedVar;` usually helps.

Comment: `// int unusedVar;`

Comment: (void) in front of the variable causes an error, and I'd rather not comment it out as I need to keep the line as part of the compile to check it.  Other suggestions?

Comment: [No errors for me](https://rextester.com/QYBG47520). You must have done something wrong.

Comment: I just figured out you were implying to put (void)unusedVar; on the next line, which now works for me as well.  Still, I'd rather not add an additional line of code if there is some way to make a Suppress comment work.

Comment: You can try the [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) attribute: `[[maybe_unused]] int unusedVar;` if your compiler support it.